# Getting Bootstrap Carousel slides to work

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

Im trying to implement bootstrap carousel slides, that show gif short clips when passed on to the next page. I've tried multiple ways including the Documentation in Bootstrap and answers from stackoverflow. The slide just wont pass to the next page.. could anyone offer any help?

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <h2>About me</h2>
      <ul style="list-style-type:none; text-align: left;">
        <li>languages: Java, JS, HTML, CSS</li>
        <li>Frameworks: Bootstrap, e</li>
        <li>Tools:</li>
        <li>Editor Journey:</li>
        <li>Operating System:</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <h2>Project 1</h2>
            <img class="project1" src="videos/QuickGame.gif" alt="First Game">
            <em>Shooter Game, Java</em>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <h2>Project 2</h2>
            <img class="project2" src="videos/DiceGame.gif" alt="Dice Game">
            <em>Dice Game, JavaScript</em>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Did any of the answers solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Did you included the below JS before the closing `</body>` tag?

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Source: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/

Answer (score 0):

As the official `bootstrap-4` [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/) says:

> Many of our components require the use of JavaScript to function. Specifically, they require jQuery, Popper.js, and our own JavaScript plugins. Place the following s near the end of your pages, right before the closing  tag, to enable them. jQuery must come first, then Popper.js, and then our JavaScript plugins.

You need to include these `<script>` right before your `</body>`:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In official [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/getting-started/introduction/) the **Carousel** component for all slide behaviors, controls, and indicators, requires JavaScript. As we can read more:

### JS

> Many of our components require the use of JavaScript to function.
> Specifically, they require jQuery, Popper, and our own JavaScript
> plugins. We use jQuery’s slim build, but the full version is also
> supported.
>
> Place one of the following s near the end of your pages, right
> before the closing  tag, to enable them. jQuery must come
> first, then Popper, and then our JavaScript plugins.

---

Your code (**suggests working harder on it**), with links hooked up properly, *bootstrap@4.6.1*

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <h2>About me</h2>
      <ul style="list-style-type:none; text-align: left;">
        <li>languages: Java, JS, HTML, CSS</li>
        <li>Frameworks: Bootstrap, e</li>
        <li>Tools:</li>
        <li>Editor Journey:</li>
        <li>Operating System:</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <h2>Project 1</h2>
            <img class="project1" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1639975721073-3ef4e6d2d4cf?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwzNXx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="First Game">
            <em>Shooter Game, Java</em>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <h2>Project 2</h2>
            <img class="project2" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1640043285014-3d1e095b3ebe?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHw1fHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="Dice Game">
            <em>Dice Game, JavaScript</em>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Option 1: jQuery and Bootstrap Bundle (includes Popper) -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-fQybjgWLrvvRgtW6bFlB7jaZrFsaBXjsOMm/tB9LTS58ONXgqbR9W8oWht/amnpF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```